# Is this structure valid?

Tags: java

I want to create a compact method tu calculate the summ of the first 20 even numbers and the multiplication of the first 20 odd numbers. is this correct?

```
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++) {
            (i % 2 == 0) ? (sumEven +=i;) : (productoImpares *= i;)
    }
```

Comment: @Eran and run it

Comment: Please explain what you hope to gain with this over the more straightforward `if(i % 2 == 0) { sumEven +=i; } else {productoImpares *= i;}`

Comment: No, it's not correct in Java. Java doesn't allow just any expression to be used as a statement. (It would be syntactically correct with a small change in some other languages that do.) If you tried to compile the code, you'd get an error. Instead, you have to use an `if`/`else` statement. (Posting answer as comment so you can delete the question. You can't delete the question if there's an upvoted answer, or more than one answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary conditional expression produces a value. You must do something with that value (assign it to a variable, return it from your method, etc...).

In your case, you are assigning to one of two different variables based on a condition.
It doesn't make much sense and a normal if-else would be more readable:

```
int sumEven = 0;
int productoImpares = 1;
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sumEven += i;
    } else {
        productoImpares *= i;
    }
}
```

Now, if you insist on using the ternary conditional operator, it can be done as follows:

```
int sumEven = 0;
int productoImpares = 1;
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++) {
    int x = (i % 2 == 0) ? (sumEven += i) : (productoImpares *= i);
}
```

Note the dummy variable `x` I used to assign the value of the ternary condition expression. I advise against it.